# prevent children to be dragged with html5 draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery

As the title states I want to disable the "dragging" event for children of a draggable parent element. this might sound like a simple question but I tried different approaches without success.
What I tried so far (nothing worked):

- reading the `event.target` or similar data to find the children and stop it (I can't find the children)
- setting the parent to `z-index` to 0 in css

Here is my code example. You have to drag/drop the elements into the field first. When you write something in the new input fields and try to highlight it, the dragging event will be fired instead. That's the main Problem I have:
https://jsfiddle.net/5nt7jqyf/

I wouldn't have this problem with jquery ui draggable since the event.target is filled with the child-reference but I don't want to use the libary and stick to the native html5 solution.

Comment: Literally impossible, but maybe you could clone the parent (don't include the children), and drag the clone instead of the original. Then you need somehow to hide the original content outside of the children.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable temporary the `draggable` attribute when event is triggered by `input` target, for this you should add on `body` a `pointerdown` listener and disable the attribute there, also a `pointerup` listener where you'll enable it back:

```js
pointerdown: function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'INPUT')
    jQuery(this).attr('draggable', null);
},
pointerup: function(e) {
  if (!jQuery(this).attr('draggable'))
    jQuery(this).attr('draggable', true);
}
```

Comment: yeah, I am actually trying the same (except that I used mousedown) atm. I wans't sure if there would be a race condition between mousedown/ponterdown and draggable handler though.

Comment: The `dragstart` event fires after `mousedown/ponterdown` so there should be no problem with this.